# How to create a Color picker like this image of color picker

Tags: android, color-picker

This picture is a screenshot of an exiting app.
Uses color picker both of steches and round selection.
 anyone help me how can I create a color picker like this one.

[image]

Comment: Please show us the code explaining your attempt/s.

Comment: dear friend Naveed, this isn't code writing service. please show us what you have attempted to achieve this in order to get proper solution for your problem.

Comment: Sure, what kind of help do you need? Just don;t say you need somebody to do entire code instead of you.

Comment: If you don't find the same then you can take the help of existing libraries [like](https://github.com/jaredrummler/ColorPicker) and modified the view according to your need.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For Simplicity you can use the existing library for color pickers, it's better not to reinvent the wheels and use the existing one.
[Here](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/18?sort=rating&category=1) is some top library for this.

Comment: I want to use holocolorpicker library  in my project.That was Deepak suggested to me. But really do'nt know how to add it in my project

Comment: Add the dependencies to the build.gradle file and then use the xml tag in your layout file

Comment: Can I use it for my own activity. Play with it without any copyright fear. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Obviously, you can as it is an open source library and that's the beauty of the open source. All you have to do is to **mention the library license and copyright** whenever you upload it on the internet (like GitHub, play store etc.)

Comment: Thanks deepak I have done without adding it to build.gradle as a dependency . I have added its java files to java folder and dimens & attrs added to values .also I have changed the pakage name of java files. Import com.mycompany.myapp.R; changed from orignal . And got a result as I wanted to be ..cheers

Answer (score 0):

As i can see that you need recent color at bottom part.
Well there is many libs are available.
[Here is one of them.](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6579)
if you don't need same design of the lib. then setup code of lib in you system and customize the design as per your requirement.